# How can i create a file and save it in local system using Blob in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, fileapi

During implementation of file transfer use case through WebRTC protocol, i am recieving data from queue at reciever end in some variables but unable to use that. Through some digging, i came to know that it can be done using Blob,
code snippet that i used :

```
var data=reciever.dequeue();
if(data)
{ var blob = new Blob(_base64ToArrayBuffer(data), {type: 'text/plain'});
  // need to know how to proceed now?
}
```

file is need to be saved in local system.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want the browser to download this file and save it?

Comment: yes,on the recieving end browser sould download the file or create download link for the same.

Comment: Can you check my answer below, I think this can satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp anchor element element and append it to document.body, trigger click event. Done.

Here is the demo code:

```
var url = objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); //your blob object here
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.href = url;
anchor.download = "YourFileName";
anchor.click(); //This will trigger browser download event.
```

[Here is document about blob to URL.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)

[Here is the blob document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Hope this works. : )